# Do containers of primitive types in C# use value semantics or pointer/reference semantics?

Tags: c#

When a `List<>` of primitive types is created in C# (e.g. a `List<int>`), are the elements inside the list stored by value, or are they stored by reference?

In other words, is C# `List<int>` equivalent to C++ `std::vector<int>` or to C++ `std::vector<shared_ptr<int>>`?

Comment: @fontanini: How can I "try myself"??

Comment: You would need to have a mutable value type to determine if/where copies were being made, and testing it would be non-trivial if you didn't already understand exactly how it worked, so no, trying it yourself wouldn't be all that easy.

Comment: Create a list of ints. Create an int. Insert it into the list. Modify the original int. Print the value of the int that you stored in the list. If they're equal, then it's passed as reference, otherwise, by value.

Comment: Although you mention C++ and provice C++ psudocode, this isn't a C++ question -- so I've removed that tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `List<int>` will have an `int[]` internally. No boxing is required usually - the values are stored directly in the array. Of course if you choose to use the `List<T>` as a non-generic `IList`, where the API is defined in terms of `object`, that *will* box:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();

// No boxing or unboxing here
list1.Add(5);
int x = list1[0];

// Perfectly valid - but best avoided
IList list2 = new List<int>();

// Boxed by the caller, then unboxed internally in the implementation
list2.Add(5);

// Boxed in the implementation, then unboxed by the caller
int y = (int) list2[0];
```

Note that the phrase "stored by reference" is a confusing one - the term "by reference" is usually used in the context of *parameter passing* where it's somewhat different.

So while a `List<string>` (for example) contains an array where each element value is a reference, in a `List<int>` each element value is simply an `int`. The only references involved are the callers reference to the `List<int>`, and the internal reference to the array. (Array types themselves are *always* reference types, even if the element type is a value type.)

Answer (score 0):

Value types are stored by value. (e.g. primitives and structs) Reference types are stored by reference. (e.g. classes)

Comment: The phrase "by reference" isn't a useful one here, IMO. It's too reminiscent of "pass by reference" which is somewhat different. For reference types, the element values simply *are* references.

Comment: All lists store values.  For classes, the value happens to simply be a reference, but it's still stored by value.  (In the same way that all parameters are passed by value unless explicitly using out/ref.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, Servy: That's what I was intending to convey, but didn't know how to state in a less confusing way.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I'm not sure why the term 'reference' was chosen over pointer in C#, because that's what reference types are, and what passing by reference means (and passing a reference type by reference is a pointer-to-pointer, or double indirection). Its usually easier to talk about reference types and references when you just think in terms of pointers.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: C# has pointers, and they're not the same as references. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/07/references-and-pointers-part-one.aspx

Comment: I know that C# has pointers and that they are different from references, but references are implemented internally using pointers, have pointer symantics, and are easier to wrap your head around when you think about them in pointer symantics. That's really all I'm saying here, but I can say that I have not learned the actual implementation details of a reference. Eric makes a point that the purpose of a pointer is to manipulate the variable itself as data, rather than the value of the variable as data, and that part I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: References *might* be implemented internally as pointers. They don't *have* to be. They're *just* ways of navigating to an object. See http://blog.juma.me.uk/2008/10/14/32-bit-or-64-bit-jvm-how-about-a-hybrid/ for example - unfortunately the links don't work, but it's about a JVM mode where references are "compressed" to allow many references to be stored as 32-bit values even in a 64-bit address space.

Answer (score 0):

So what would happen if you wrote code like this:

```
struct MutableValueType
{
  public int ChangableInt32;
}

static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
     var li = new List<MutableValueType>();
     li.Add(new MutableValueType());
     li[0].ChangableInt32 = 42;
  }
}
```

Will you modify a copy of your struct, or will you change the copy that is inside the `List<>`? Will the compiler warn you? I would like to try this.